Email authentication Issue with PHPMailer and SES
I am trying to send a mail from my PHP code in my EC2 container using SES. I want to add role-based permission for sending mail (I don't want to use username and password).
For the IAM user I have attached the policy below:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

And I am using the following code to send the test email:
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
    $mail->Host       = $strSesHostName;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->Port       = 465;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($strFromMail, 'Prifulnath');
    $mail->addAddress($strToMail);

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'SES Test Email';
    $mail->Body    = 'Test email body';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

But when running this code I am getting SMTP errors as shown here:
2024-08-28 11:17:48 Connection: opening to ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2024-08-28 11:17:48 Connection: opened
2024-08-28 11:17:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-UF5383B18 BKsi60z05CMePrzvSC8r
2024-08-28 11:17:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO test.mydomain.org
2024-08-28 11:17:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com250-8BITMIME250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 Ok
2024-08-28 11:17:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<noreply@mydomain.com>
2024-08-28 11:17:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 530 Authentication required
2024-08-28 11:17:48 SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed: 530 Authentication required
The following From address failed: noreply@mydomain.com : MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication required,530,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication required SMTP code: 530
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: The following From address failed: noreply@mydomain.com : MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication required ,530,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication required SMTP code: 530SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication required SMTP code: 5302024-08-28 11:17:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-08-28 11:17:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 Bye
2024-08-28 11:17:48 Connection: closed

Can anyone please help me to figure out the issue?

I'd expect that you can set up an app password that might allow you to use regular SMTP auth.
